# This CSS class is getting hidden by ad blockers

Tags: css, twitter, adblock

Most ad blockers have no problem with this class, but some hide the entire anchor block. I get some web visitors report "Hey, some of the text is missing from your page." It's a class for hotlinked text that sends a tweet. Example:

```
<a href="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=They%20stand%20motionless%20in%20long%20black%20cloaks.&amp;url=http%3A%2F%2Fskep.us/4522" class="twit_quote">They stand motionless in long black cloaks.</a>
```

The CSS class "twit_quote" makes it hover blue with a little birdie icon. Anything I can change to make it adblocker friendly?

Comment: Add it to your list of exceptions in Adblock.

Comment: You could ask your visitors whether they got [Adblock Plus' "Disable Social Media Buttons" feature](https://adblockplus.org/features#socialmedia) enabled. It's using [Fanboy's Social Blocking List](https://easylist.to/#fanboy-s-social-blocking-list) which gets rid of all kinds of social media elements on websites.

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing which adblocker is hiding the link, or what your URL is, it's not possible to tell you specifically which filter is actively blocking the text.

FYI -- if you check EasyList, the class name `twit_quote` does not get blocked, but it could be some other list other than EasyList

That having been said, there are a couple things you can try:

1) Try creating a new class name with the same properties of `twit_quote` and using that class name instead.

2) Try replacing the URL in the href with a link from a URL shortener

3) It may not be this line at all, but the enclosing DIV or other element that the link is embedded in.

Comment: I've asked the last couple people who emailed reports to tell me what ad blocker they were using. Thanks.

The URL of the page was in the href in my OP, but if you missed it this will do: https://skeptoid.com/episodes/4521

Comment: One user experiencing the problem reports he's using "Adblock Plus" in the newest Safari on the newest OS X.